# java hashmap values

Tags: java, hashmap, average

My hashmap contains a key which is the customers name, and the values are all the ratings for the books rated. I have to calculate the average rating for a given booktitle.

How do I access all of the values (ratings) from the hashmap? Is there a method for doing this?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
/** 
 * calculate the average rating by all customers for a named book
 * only count positive or negative ratings, not 0 (unrated)
 * if the booktitle is not found or their are no ratings then
 * return NO_AVERAGE
 * @param booktitle String to be rated
 * @return double the average of all ratings for this book
 */
public double averageRating(String booktitle) 
{ 
    numberOfRatingsPerCustomer/total
}
```

Comment: A hashmap maps a key to a single value. Can you clarify what your data structure is?

Comment: All Java `Maps` (including HashMaps) have a [method named `values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) which returns a collection of values.

Comment: okay i am trying to create a data structure which contains all the booklists and then the costumer rates the books under his/her name. 

can you please tell how to calculate the average rating

Comment: @AkanshaDahiya: Average rating = total rating / number of ratings.

Comment: i dont know how to obtain number of ratings, it wouldnt be just the size of hashmap

Comment: @AkanshaDahiya: You previously posted code in your question that obtained the number of ratings (seems to be deleted now though). What's the problem with your existing code?

Comment: its not lettng me post the code anymore but the code compiles its the test thats having difficulties
it cannot be tested because it comes up with a message for test that it cannot calculate average for double. @Test public void testAverageRating1() { double a1 = ratings.averageRating("Isaac Asimov,Foundation Series"); assertEquals(2.571,a1,DELTA); }

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the keySet from the HashMap. And then Iterate over the keySet and fetch the values from the HashMap.

Comment: This guy is right. Iterate the key set and with each key retrieve the value (which will be your ArrayList) and use it. Any more help on this stuff you should read the Java API.

Comment: It is more efficient to iterate the entrySet() than to iterate the keySet() and calculate the hash of each key to look up the values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense.

You can't have a map with `customerName` to `hisRatingOfBook`, and search in it for `bookTitle`. You need to go one of 1 ways:

1)
create method `public double averageRating()` inside `Book` class, and keep there, as field, rating being map with `customerName` to `hisRatingOfBook`

2) Use your method:

```
public double averageRating(String booktitle) 
{ 
    numberOfRatingsPerCustomer/total
}
```

but **make your map something more complex**, that will hold `customer`, and its `rating` (being made from book title + rate)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go take these below code it will help you out to find your rating problem
I have done to **find average of Student marks  in a class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueQue {

public static float getAverage(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm, String name) {
    ArrayList<Integer> scores;
    scores = hm.get(name);
    if (scores == null) {
        System.out.println("NOT found");
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : scores) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return (float) sum / scores.size();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("Peter", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);

    hm.put("Nancy", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Nancy").add(7);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);

    hm.put("Lily", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(8);

    System.out.println("Find the average of the Peter");
    float num = getAverage(hm, "Peter");

}
  }
```